# Sample error in xgboost R-studio

Tags: r, xgboost

Training model with Caret and Xgboost algorithm.
Training stops with error.

Grid setup

```
 expand.grid(nrounds = c(12,15, 17, 20, 22,24,26,28), # 
                   max_depth = c( 3, 4, 5, 6,7,8,9,10), # 
                   eta = c(.001,.05,.06,0.07,0.08,.1,.2,.3, .4), 
                   gamma = c(0, .1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7), 
                   colsample_bytree = c(.5,.6,.7, .8, .9,1),#
                   min_child_weight = c(1,2,3),# 
                   subsample = c(.6,.7,.8, .9, 1)
```

> Error in sample.int(n = 1000000L, size = num_rs * nrow(trainInfo$loop)
>   +  :    cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

Data set I have 2500 rows and 50 parameters. How can I fix this error and train model?

Comment: 400k hyperparameter combinations to search... that's intense. What combination of parameters causes the error?

Comment: Well, I don't know how to find it out. Where can i check this?

Comment: You need some sort of logging so you can tell track progress through your loop and then know where it stops. This can be as simple as output to the console via `cat()` at every iteration, listing the iteration number and maybe the current parameters.